# Is the "weekend" part of the "week"?

Tags: nouns

Is the "week" only the five days in-between weekends or not?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might find it beneficial to read [ask], as it explains how to ask good questions. Please read [the definition for week](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/week?q=week) and [the definition for weekend](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/weekend). If these do not answer your question, please edit it to explain why.

Comment: [Anything between four and ten days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week)! \\(^_^)/

Answer (score 4):

According to Oxford Dictionary, a week is a period of seven days, but a workweek is from Monday to Friday.

> week |wiːk| noun
>
> - a period of **seven days**
> - workdays as opposed to the weekend; **the five days from Monday to Friday**

I’d say it depends on the context.

Answer (score 4):

Again, context is all.

"I was going to do that in the week," for example, contrasts with "...at the weekend" and so *week* there does not include the weekend.

"The week ending 29 July 2012" obviously does include the weekend.

Comment: In dmckee's comment at [question 8148](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8148/would-sir-like-something-for-the-weekend) one finds "during the week" used similarly: "... many [places] would have been closed on the weekend. So if you want... something for the weekend, you would have to buy it during the week."

Comment: True, context is all. I can say _week_ and be referring to a _work week_. Another example: when I tell my boss, "I'll get that done by the end of the week," _work week_ is generally implied, hence, I'm giving myself a Friday deadline.

Answer (score 0):

The week spans all seven days.  The standard work week, only five.